# Why is /usr/lib/default-java pointing to the "wrong" jdk?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, java-home, system-administration

I got a linux mint pc with openJDK 1.11 pre-installed. I installed the openJDK 1.8. package and set the default java (sudo update-alternatives --config java) to it. All is working fine (java -version outputs the correct java version). Now that I try to use maven, in my attempt to change JAVA_HOME (because it was not pointing to the correct location - this is working now, too), I saw a directory called default-java (/usr/lib/jvm/default-java) which is a symlink to the original 1.11 JDK, even though I am not using it at all.

Can someone tell me what that means, if that is a problem and if I should change it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to `default-java` is managed by the APT package `default-jre-headless`.

To update the link, you could remove the package and then reinstall it again

```
apt remove default-jre-headless
apt install default-jre-headless
```

Check this answer : https://askubuntu.com/questions/181381/what-package-creates-usr-lib-jvm-default-java